# Javascript - Validation on input - Can I check if character x is number and character y is letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 project and have an input which I'm wanting to do some validation on.

It is inputting an 8 character length entry with a mixture of numbers and letters. I have the input max length at 8 characters already.

What I need is to create a function to only allow entry of either a number or a letter at certain characters in the entry (see below).

1 - Letter
2 - Letter
3 - Number
4 - Letter
5 - Number
6 - Number
7 - Number
8 - Number

eg, BP1A8123

Is there a way to do that in JavaScript? I've come across examples of letters only or number only but can't find an example of number / letters at certain characters within the entry.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry what I wasn't very clear on was I did not want the user to be able to enter a number when expecting a letter or vice-versa

eg, for character 1 it would expect a letter, so if a number was tried to be keyed in it would not, but if a letter was keyed in that would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a JavaScript perspective, you could do the check like this:

```
pattern = RegExp('[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}')
pattern.test('BP1A8123') // true
pattern.text('B1111111') // false
```

From a SAPUI5 perspective, input validation is generally handled via the data binding. See, for example, this [SAPUI5 Demokit Sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview). Also see the `validationError` and `validationSuccess` events of class [`sap.ui.core.Core'](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core/events/Summary).

However, for your specific requirement, the [`sap.m.MaskInput`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MaskInput) control may be what you're after. See this [Demokit example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput/preview).

Comment: I vote for RegExp since it's simpler and get the job done. Also, OP asked for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: This RegExp example worked great thanks. I'm doing a lot of further validation with value states of components, message strips and view data binding. Just needed this reg exp to be the last part of the puzzle. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So we have the template:

```
template = ['letter', 'letter', 'number', 'letter',
            'number', 'number', 'number', 'number']
```

... and some input:

```
input = 'BP1A8123'
```

We can then just use `isNaN()` to check whether the respective characters are letters:

```
input.split('').every((c,i) => isNaN(c)  || template[i] == 'number')
```

which gives `true` in this instance.

Comment: Sorry what I wasn't very clear on was I did not want the user to be able to enter a number when expecting a letter or vice-versa

eg, for character 1 it would expect a letter, so if a number was tried to be keyed in it would not, but if a letter was keyed in that would be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string using `.split('')` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split)), parse the character into int to check if the variable is a number using `isNaN` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt)).